# Why does producer need to lock directory to create new files in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, producer-consumer

There's a producer which will download new files to a local file system (it will never modify existing files), and a consumer which periodically checks if there are new files and reads the new files.

I'm a bit confused about why the producer needs to lock the directory before creating the new file, and the consumer lock the directory when it is reading the new file, since no existing files will ever be modified so there should be no issue of a writer editing a file while the reader is reading.

Thanks

Comment: it does not need to lock the directory or files - these are also features of the filesystem and may not even be supported .. however, note that you may have a race where the file may be partially written when the consumer attempts to read it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Producing a file is not atomic. First, an empty file is created. Then its content is written to it, possibly over multiple writes. Each write modifies the file, so your claim the file is never modified is false.

A lock is being used to ensure that the consumer only picks up complete files.<sup>[1]</sup>

There are alternative approaches to locking that could be used. For example, the producer could create files suffixed with `.tmp`, then rename (not copy) the file to the correct name when the file is complete. If the consumer ignores files ending in `.tmp`, then it will only pick up complete files.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

1. Complete in the sense that the producer will never add to it again. But that doesn't mean the file contains all that it should. If the producer crashes, and if that automatically releases the lock, the consumer may receive only a part of the intended contents.
2. Truly complete. Not only will the producer never add to it again, but everything the producer intended to write to the file was written to it. (Short of a power failure at exactly the wrong moment or a similarly drastic event.)

Comment: *A lock is being used to ensure that a consumer only picks up complete files.*  Except it doesn't ensure that - if the producer for any reason doesn't complete the file before the lock gets released, or the consumer ignores the lock for any reason, incomplete files will be consumed.  Which is why the rename method you listed as an alternative is sooo much better - the rename won't happen until the file is complete, so there's no way an incomplete file can be processed.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Good point. That's a data integrity issue and not a race condition, but clarification is warranted. Note that this doesn't necessarily make the alternative approach better. Both approaches have pros and cons. For example, with the alternative approach, one now needs something to clean up the orphaned files, and the consumer is no longer able to detect the problem.

Comment: The root cause of all the problems in either alternative is the misuse of a state-based data store such as a filesystem as an event-driven communications channel. The rename method at least provides a persistent state change in the filesystem itself to emulate the event of "file is complete", something a lock does not do as the existence of the lock is independent of the state of the file. Although the rename method can require cleanup as you noted, it does remove almost all ambiguity about the state of the file. The file could be completed before rename, but that's a **small** window

Comment: @AndrewHenle some applications require files to be downloaded to multiple machines though, in which case is there an alternative to sync files without using a filesystem?